# React.js: Pass value from form to axios POST request

Tags: reactjs

I'm very confused with what I am doing right now

I'm trying to pass form data into an axios POST request and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong

Here is the code of the form:

**ClientMaintenancePage.js**

```
const [dataBanks, setDataBanks] = useState([]);
const [optionsBrstn, setOptionsBrstn] = useState('');

...

const retrieveBanks = useCallback(() => {
ClientMaintenanceService.retrieveBanks()
.then((response) => {
  console.log("ClientMaintenancePage - retrieveBanks response.data >>> " + response.data)
  setDataBanks(response.data);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log("ClientMaintenancePage - retrieveBanks catch >>> " + err)
})
});

const saveBrstn = useCallback(() => {
ClientMaintenanceService.saveBankMaintenance(optionsBrstn)
.then((response) => {
  console.log("ClientMaintenancePage - saveBrstn response.data >>> " + response.data)
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log("ClientMaintenancePage - saveBrstn catch >>> " + err)
})
});

useEffect(() => {
retrieveBanks();
}, []);

...

const newOptions = dataBanks.map(({BIC, BRSTN, NAME}) => ({
label: BIC + "  " + BRSTN + "  " + NAME ,
value: BRSTN
}))

return (
<Select 
          id="selectBrstn"
          isSearchable="true"
          options={ newOptions } 
          placeholder="Select BIC / BRSTN / Bank Name..." 
          value={ optionsBrstn }
          onChange={ setOptionsBrstn }
        />
)
```

I'm trying to save the value of dropdown

So I'm passing the value to axios POST request. However, I can't get the value properly

Please enlighten me on what am I missing.

Also, here is the code of my POST request:

**ClientMaintenanceService.js**

```
const LOCAL_API_URL_SAVE_BANK_MAINTENANCE = "http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8080/cpex/bank/maintenance/save"

saveBankMaintenance(optionsBrstn){
    console.log("saveBankMaintenance axios.post - optionsBrstn >>> " + optionsBrstn)
    return axios.post(`${LOCAL_API_URL_SAVE_BANK_MAINTENANCE}`, {
        brstn: optionsBrstn
    })
}
```

If I'm correct, I think have the value of the dropdown in my state *optionsBrstn*

I passed it as a paramter on my service call but somehow I don't get it as String

TIA

Comment: At first you should check the output of `Select`, then write a function for `onChange` and log the output. if output is correct data(that you need) then you can set in `state`.Be sure your `Select` export a string value.

Comment: I tried to use JSON.stringify in the output of Select object. It showed this value: {"label":"BOFAPH2XXXX  010120019  BANK OF AMERICA NATL ASSN","value":"010120019"}. Is there a way I can only get the value?

Comment: Your `Select` is a custom component or from `material-ui` or other library? can you tell where you imported from?

Comment: import Select from 'react-select'; It is a custom library called react-select. Please see https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select

Answer (score 0):

Value of `react-select` is one of (object,array of object,null and undefined).

Then if you need to property of object as value, you have three options:

1- Create a custom component and use `react-select` inside it and write custom `onChange` and return the property of object that you need into custom `onChange`.

2- If you always don't need to property of object as value of `Select`, you should write your own `onChange` instead of `setOptionsBrstn` directly.

```
const onChange=(outputObject)=>{
  setOptionsBrstn(output.yourProperty)
}

<Select 
  ...
  onChange={onChange}
  ...
/>
```

3- You can get an object in `saveBankMaintenance` as parameter and use a property of object that you need.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried option 2 since it looks easier. However, I'm getting error since I'm also new in ecmascript. const onChangeBrstnDropdown = (outputObject) => {
    setOptionsBrstn(outputObject.value)
  }

Comment: At first into `onChangeBrstnDropdown` write `console.log(outputObject)` to see what's ouput.(without any JSON.stringify)

Comment: Is this the correct way to call `onChangeBrstnDropdown`? `onChange={ onChangeBrstnDropdown() }`

Comment: You must use `onChangeBrstnDropdown` like my answer or `onChange={(data)=> onChangeBrstnDropdown(data) }`. You don't need to use condition.

Comment: Ok I followed what you did. Called `onChange` directly, however, when I console.log `outputObject`. I get an error that it is undefined

Comment: If you use the code in answer it will be ok.It's better show your code or example to solve the problem.(Also `react-select` has many features)